# Type family error

Tags: haskell, types, functional-programming, type-families

Hello I wrote my first program with type family

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}

data Colist a = Colist (Maybe (a,Colist a))

class Listable l where type Item l :: *
    toList :: l -> [Item l]

instance Listable (Colist a) where 
    type Item (Colist a) = (Colist a)
    toList x = [x]
```

The program should take Colist a and take it into a list
I get the error that 'Item l' couldn't be matched with actual type 'l'. But I wrote that the Item x EQUALS (Colist a). Where is my mistake?

Comment: I think you meant `type Item (Colist a) = a`. And you probably meant `toList` to be a method of `Listable`?

Comment: You need to include the code that causes the error if you want a good explanation. This code loads just fine (after fixing indentation errors). That said: it is because, like all type family first-timers, you have not yet understood what "type families are not injective" means.

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/bIjXI I get this error

Comment: Don't post images of text on SO -- copy & paste the actual error text message inside your question, so that everyone will notice that and read it immediately. Hiding important information under a link to an image makes it less likely others will simply skip the question, providing no help.

Answer (score 2):

Did you mean...

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}

newtype List a = List (Maybe (a, List a))

class Listable l where
    type Item l :: *
    toList :: l -> [Item l]

instance Listable (List a) where
    type Item (List a) = a

    toList (List Nothing) = []
    toList (List (Just (x, xs)) = x : toList xs
```

I've changed a few things about your code. Zero, I renamed `Colist` to `List` (because there's no such thing as a coinductive list in Haskell). One, I fixed the indentation, making `toList` a method of the `Listable` class. Two, I made `List a`'s instance of `Item` return `a`, not `List a`. Three, I fixed `toList` to actually return a list of the elements of the `List` - your version just put the whole `List` in a singleton list.

I strongly suspect you're misusing type families here though. Here's a much simpler and more Haskell-ish formulation of this class:

```
class Listable l where
    toList :: l a -> [a]

instance Listable List where
    toList (List Nothing) = []
    toList (List (Just (x, xs)) = x : toList xs
```

Or you can just derive `Foldable` and get `toList` for free:

```
newtype List a = List (Maybe (a, List a)) deriving Foldable

ghci> import Data.Foldable
ghci> toList $ List (Just ('a', List Nothing))
"a"
```

Comment: An inductive list would be `data List a = Nil | Cons !a !(List a)`, no?

Comment: Also ... I don't consider this stripped down version of `MonoFoldable` to be unreasonable. Unlike `Functor` and `Traverseable`, the higher kind of `Foldable` only offers extra power under special circumstances (polymorphic recursion, for example). And some important instances, like unboxed arrays, can't be `Foldable`.

Comment: @dfeuer I never said it was unreasonable, `MonoFoldable` is indeed a useful class. From reading the question, though, I suspect the questioneer is a beginner, so to me it felt pedagogically justified to point the questioneer towards `Foldable` :)

Comment: I mean to say, I think the extra power of `MonoFoldable` (in that it has a larger number of instances) is not justified by the extra complexity, if you’re a beginner who’s learning to use the class system